# How to check window/block width durring server side rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have react app with server side rendering. I use window object in my component in order to get window width and place elements on the center of the page. As I use ssr, I get error in the console that `window is not defined`.

How can I remove this error or how can I get window or block width and use it during rendering?
Here is the code of my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';

import SectionBackground from '../SectionBackground';

import Styles from './styles.scss';

export default class Section extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
    this.state = {     
      windowWidth: 0,
      circleSecondLine: 0,
      circleThirdLine: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {       
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  setCenterPosition() {    
     return this.state.width ? this.state.width / 2 : window.innerWidth / 2;
  }

  setLine() {
    let lineVPosiotion = 0;
    const { innerWidth } = window;
    if (innerWidth <= 768) {
      lineVPosiotion = 62;
    } else if (innerWidth <= 1023) {
      lineVPosiotion = 200;
    } else {
      lineVPosiotion = 300;
    }
    const coords = `M${this.state.width},0 v${lineVPosiotion}`;
    return coords;
  }

  handleResize() {
    this.setState({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
    });
    this.setLine();  
  }

  render() {
    const sectionTemplate = {       
      setLine: this.setChatLine,     
      setCenterCircle: this.setCenterPosition,
    };
    return (
      <div className={Styles['anim-background']} ref={this.ref}>
        <SectionBackground {...sectionTemplate} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On what row are you getting the `window is not defined` error?

Comment: in setCenterPosition() during server rendering. Actually in every row where window is used

Comment: You could try `setCenterPosition() { if (typeof window === "undefined") { return 0; } else { return this.state.width ? ... } }`. You can't know anything about the window when server side rendering sadly.

Comment: is there other way to get the center on the block? I mean replacing window with something other

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it's dependent on how it is rendered in the browser, so it will be difficult to figure that out beforehand on the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code on server side it actually don't know about window or document. You need to register window globally. For that you can include `jsdom-global/register` in your start script of `package.json` and before starting the server you can make sure that window instance is available globally.

`"start": "jsdom-global/register node ./dist/server"`

Install below packages  first:

`"jsdom": "11.11.0",
 "jsdom-global": "3.0.2"`

Hope this will work!